# Ordenar matriz de n linhas tendo como critério o valor da coluna em C

Tags: c, funções, matriz

Tenho o seguinte código :

```
int** ordena(int **v, int tam)
{
   int i, j,aux;
   int swap[3];
   for (i = 0; i > (tam-1); i++){
      aux = i;
      for (j = (i+1); j > tam; j++) {
         if(v[j][1] > v[aux][1]) {
            aux = j;
         }
      }
      if (i != aux) {
         swap[0] = v[i][0];
         swap[1] = v[i][1];
         swap[2] = v[i][2];
         v[i][0] = v[aux][0];
         v[i][1] = v[aux][1];
         v[i][2] = v[aux][2];
         v[aux][0] = swap[0];
         v[aux][1] = swap[1];
         v[aux][2] = swap[2];
     }
  }
return v;

}
```

Nao estou a perceber porque é que não esta a ordenar pela segunda coluna da matriz. Executo o código e devolve a mesma matriz inicial desordenada pela 2 coluna. A matriz é de 3 colunas por n linhas. E quero ordenar a matriz trocando a linha que esta desordenada em relação a seguinte tendo em conta o valor da coluna 2 de cada linha.
Exemplo

2 3 4

3 7 9

1 1 1

5 2 4

Saída

1 1 1

5 2 4

2 3 4

3 7 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que se passa é que tem erros pequenos nos `fors` e `ifs`, que eu suspeito que sejam distrações:

```
for (i = 0; i > (tam-1); i++){
//------------^ aqui tem de ser <
  aux = i;
  for (j = (i+1); j > tam; j++) {
  //----------------^ e aqui também <
     if(v[j][1] > v[aux][1]) {
     //---------^ aqui também < para ter a ordenação do menor para o maior
        aux = j;
     }
  }
```

Com essas alterações já funciona como pretende.

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/KO8hK0)

Deixo no entanto a nota de que o retorno de `int**` que tem não faz sentido pois a função altera o array recebido diretamente, e retornar o array de entrada em nada adianta. Por este motivo o tipo de retorno devia ser `void`.